# Matplot Legend Text Font size using R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to plot a graph using the below code, but i am unable to change the font size of the legend.
Please suggest the change/edit to make the legend text legible.

```
Seasons <- c("2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014")

#Players
Players <- c("KobeBryant","JoeJohnson","LeBronJames","CarmeloAnthony","DwightHoward","ChrisBosh","ChrisPaul","KevinDurant","DerrickRose","DwayneWade")


#Games 
KobeBryant_G <- c(80,77,82,82,73,82,58,78,6,35)
JoeJohnson_G <- c(82,57,82,79,76,72,60,72,79,80)
LeBronJames_G <- c(79,78,75,81,76,79,62,76,77,69)
CarmeloAnthony_G <- c(80,65,77,66,69,77,55,67,77,40)
DwightHoward_G <- c(82,82,82,79,82,78,54,76,71,41)
ChrisBosh_G <- c(70,69,67,77,70,77,57,74,79,44)
ChrisPaul_G <- c(78,64,80,78,45,80,60,70,62,82)
KevinDurant_G <- c(35,35,80,74,82,78,66,81,81,27)
DerrickRose_G <- c(40,40,40,81,78,81,39,0,10,51)
DwayneWade_G <- c(75,51,51,79,77,76,49,69,54,62)

#Field Goals
KobeBryant_FG <- c(978,813,775,800,716,740,574,738,31,266)
JoeJohnson_FG <- c(632,536,647,620,635,514,423,445,462,446)
LeBronJames_FG <- c(875,772,794,789,768,758,621,765,767,624)
CarmeloAnthony_FG <- c(756,691,728,535,688,684,441,669,743,358)
DwightHoward_FG <- c(468,526,583,560,510,619,416,470,473,251)
ChrisBosh_FG <- c(549,543,507,615,600,524,393,485,492,343)
ChrisPaul_FG <- c(407,381,630,631,314,430,425,412,406,568)
KevinDurant_FG <- c(306,306,587,661,794,711,643,731,849,238)
DerrickRose_FG <- c(208,208,208,574,672,711,302,0,58,338)
DwayneWade_FG <- c(699,472,439,854,719,692,416,569,415,509)
#Matrix
FieldGoals <- rbind(KobeBryant_FG, JoeJohnson_FG, LeBronJames_FG, CarmeloAnthony_FG, DwightHoward_FG, ChrisBosh_FG, ChrisPaul_FG, KevinDurant_FG, DerrickRose_FG, DwayneWade_FG)
rm(KobeBryant_FG, JoeJohnson_FG, LeBronJames_FG, CarmeloAnthony_FG, DwightHoward_FG, ChrisBosh_FG, ChrisPaul_FG, KevinDurant_FG, DerrickRose_FG, DwayneWade_FG)
colnames(FieldGoals) <- Seasons
rownames(FieldGoals) <- Players


FieldGoals_1 <- t(FieldGoals)

FieldGoals_1
matplot(FieldGoals_1, type ="b", cex = 0.01, pch = 15:18, col = c(1:4,6))
legend("bottomleft",  inset = c(0,0) , cex = 0.15, horiz = T, col = c(1:4,6), legend = Players)
```

This is the plot i could generate with above code:-

[image]

Comment: since we don't have any data for FieldGoals_1 or Players, or any picture of what's wrong with your plot, how can we know what's wrong with it? If you have 4 players and a 4x4 matrix for field goals, the plot looks fine. If you have 20 players, then they won't fit on the page. When you say you want the text legible, what's wrong with it? It could be too small, the wrong font, the wrong color, overlaid on other text, clipped, printed off the page, etc. Please help us to help you by editing your post to add your data. Do `dput(FieldGoals_1)` and `dput(Players)` then copy and paste as code.

Comment: Apologies for not specifying the problem clearly, i have ow edited it.

Comment: thank you. Please see my answer which should hopefully resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `cex` argument of `legend`. A little playing around with the parameters like this:

```r
matplot(FieldGoals_1, type ="b", cex = 0.01, pch = 15:18, col = c(1:4,6))
legend("bottomleft",  inset = c(0,0) , cex = 0.55, col = c(1:4,6), 
       lty = 1, lwd = 2, ncol = 5, legend = Players)
```

Gives you this:
[image]

An alternative (and better looking) approach would be to tidy your data into long format and use `ggplot`, which gives a legend seperate from the main plot area:

```r
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(FieldGoals)                                     %>%
  mutate(Players = Players)                                   %>%
  pivot_longer(-Players)                                      %>%
  select(Players = Players, Year = name, Field_Goals = value) %>%
  mutate(Year = as.POSIXct(paste0(Year, "-01-01"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Field_Goals, colour = Players)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Players)) +
  labs(y = "Field goals per year", title = "Field goals")
```

[image]

Comment: it's still not working for me, the text of the legend is too small & not at all legible

Comment: @renu did you try increasing the `cex`  value in the `legend` function?